# Can't hear anything when I launch TF2?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, macos

I started up TF2 and was playing, when suddenly, my sound cut out. I've tried `snd_restart` however it also affects YouTube videos in the background.

I can hear sound fine when TF2 isn't running.

I don't know if it's related, but when I use voice chat my game lags as well.

I am using a Mac if it matters.